# Firebase access token using getAuth()

Tags: authorization, firebase

I am wondering if firebase function getAuth() somehow checks if the the website link to which the token was initially issued is the one that is requesting for the authorization status.

I am concerned that if a malicious website somehow had access to my Firebase.io link, and runs a simple getAuth() in the same browser as my Firebase based backend website, it will be able to access the Firebase token issued to the user of my website.

Any thoughts on it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I work at Firebase*

Firebase Authentication sessions are stored using LocalStorage accessible  *only to your domain*. This means that the sessions are not accessible from domains outside of your control.

If you're using OAuth (Google, Facebook, Twitter, or GitHub login), then authentication is *further* restricted to your domain via our OAuth configuration in your Firebase dashboard, where you must explicitly authorize domains for access.

Users of email / password authentication can authenticate from any source, *provided that the user has access to the password*. In short, we ensure that the sessions stored for your domain are not accessible elsewhere. Our top priorities for this product are data security and making that security available to you (as the developer) easily and as the default.

If you have additional concerns that are sensitive for any reason, don't hesitate to reach out to me rob at firebase.com.